# how to migrate SQL server's data to mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am trying to migrate my database from SQL server to mongoDB, I've exported tables from my database, and wrote the corresponding mongoDB import function for it:

```
mongoimport -d dashboard -c col --type csv --file "C:/Users/sesa356116/text.csv" --headerline -f bu_id,bu_name,bu_id,
```

this is getting executed, but when I am trying to see the data in robomongo,  no records are getting displayed. What I want to know is after this import function are there any further steps that should be followed in order to get the corresponding records, any leads for the same will be helpful.

Comment: What does the output of `mongoimport` say? If it ran successfully it should say some thing like "Imported 100 records" at the end. Does it say that? If not, what error messages are there? How are you checking that data is imported? Your command looks invalid, since it doesn't make sense to have both the `--headerline` and `-f` options specified.

Comment: yes it ran successfully, I mean, I got "39 files imported", in the command statement if I am skipping any of them i.e. headerline and f, it's giving me error.

Comment: Can you show how you are looking for the imported documents?